# Use Header Enricher/SpEL to parse connection ID and look up in Map

Tags: spring-integration

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` which maps server connections to client 
connections:

```
{localhost:6080:50848:42a5d558-6264-4f2f-83c4-5a9964e1d168=localhost:50847:6060:a7da2280-abe3-4fce-9650-4e8a0ae31891}
```

I need to use a Header Enricher to intercept an incoming Message, parse its 
current `ip_connectionId` header, look up that key in my map, and update `ip_connectionId` with the value.

```
    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel="responseChannel1", outputChannel="responseChannel2")
    public HeaderEnricher responseEnricher() {

        Map<String, HeaderValueMessageProcessor<?>> headersToAdd = new HashMap<>();

        Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("headers['ip_connectionId']");

        try {
            String serverConnectionId = expression.getValue(String.class);
            log.info(serverConnectionId);

            String clientConnectionId = outboundToInboundMap.get(serverConnectionId);
            log.info(clientConnectionId);

            headersToAdd.put("ip_connectionId", new StaticHeaderValueMessageProcessor<>(clientConnectionId));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HeaderEnricher enricher = new HeaderEnricher(headersToAdd);
        enricher.setDefaultOverwrite(true);
        return enricher;
    }
```

When I run this, I do not see the log statements, and I still get this error:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket
```

because the `ip_connectionId` header was not changed.

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a `@Bean` and you try to do an active, runtime operation against your `outboundToInboundMap` during bean definition phase. That's really a fact that do that `outboundToInboundMap.get()` here is too early and you really don't have anything in that map yet.

What you need to do is really perform a logic at runtime, when a send operation to that `responseChannel1` happens. For that purpose you can't use a `StaticHeaderValueMessageProcessor`. What you need is exactly an `ExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor`:

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel="responseChannel1", outputChannel="responseChannel2")
public HeaderEnricher responseEnricher() {

    Map<String, HeaderValueMessageProcessor<?>> headersToAdd = new HashMap<>();

    headersToAdd.put("ip_connectionId", 
       new ExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor<>("@outboundToInboundMap[headers['ip_connectionId']]", String .class));

    HeaderEnricher enricher = new HeaderEnricher(headersToAdd);
    enricher.setDefaultOverwrite(true);
    return enricher;
}
```

This way an expression is going to be evaluated at runtime against a request message and you need to have that `outboundToInboundMap` as bean with an appropriate name. I used an `outboundToInboundMap`, but you may change that bean reference to your real bean name for the map.

Comment: You probably also need logic to handle missing entries.

Comment: Right, that's our next step. Thanks to both of you